How to resolve ClickableText deprecation related to LinkAnnotation in Jetpack Compose?
I have the following component in compose:
private const val GROUP_NAME_TAG = "groupName"

@Composable
fun ExpenseHeaderGroupWithDateText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    date: ShimmerInformation<String>,
    groupName: String,
    groupNameClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    date.ToContent(
        loadingModifier = modifier
            .height(15.dp)
            .width(50.dp),
    ) { safeDate ->
        val annotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    color = Black300,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                )
            ) {
                append("$safeDate ${stringResource(id = R.string.in_connector)} ")
            }
            pushStringAnnotation(
                tag = GROUP_NAME_TAG,
                annotation = groupName
            )
            withStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    color = Black300,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                    textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
                )
            ) {
                append(groupName)
            }
            pop()
        }
        ClickableText(
            modifier = modifier,
            text = annotatedText,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
            onClick = { offset ->
                annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(
                    tag = GROUP_NAME_TAG,
                    start = offset,
                    end = offset
                ).firstOrNull()?.let { _ ->
                    groupNameClick()
                }
            },
        )
    }
}

I'm reciving the following warning about my ClickableText composable:
Use Text or BasicText and pass an AnnotatedString that contains a LinkAnnotation
I have already tried with Text and BasicText but I didn't find a parameter to put this LinkAnnotation.

I changed the ClickableText for the following (it works):
Text(
    modifier = modifier.clickable {
        // Get the annotation where the click occurred
        val annotation = annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(
            tag = GROUP_NAME_TAG,
            start = 0,
            end = annotatedText.length
        ).firstOrNull()

        if (annotation != null) {
            groupNameClick()
        }
    },
    text = annotatedText,
    style = TextStyle.Default,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    maxLines = 1
)

My final code:
@Composable
fun ExpenseHeaderGroupWithDateText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    date: ShimmerInformation<String>,
    groupName: String,
    groupNameClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    date.ToContent(
        loadingModifier = modifier
            .height(15.dp)
            .width(50.dp),
    ) { safeDate ->
        val annotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                )
            ) {
                append("$safeDate ${stringResource(id = R.string.in_connector)} ")
            }
            pushStringAnnotation(
                tag = GROUP_NAME_TAG,
                annotation = groupName
            )
            withStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                    textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
                )
            ) {
                append(groupName)
            }
            pop()
        }

        Text(
            modifier = modifier.clickable {
                // Get the annotation where the click occurred
                val annotation = annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(
                    tag = GROUP_NAME_TAG,
                    start = 0,
                    end = annotatedText.length
                ).firstOrNull()

                if (annotation != null) {
                    groupNameClick()
                }
            },
            text = annotatedText,
            style = TextStyle.Default,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1
        )
    }
}

